# How to check if the libdvdcss library is contained in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, dvd, shared-library, media-library

I am using ubuntu studio 16.04. Except from adding a few PPAs, I've not changed the system as it was after the installation.

I am wondering if the library libdvdcss is installed, here is why:

After having put the DVD "[F.T.W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F.T.W._(film))" starring Mickey Rourke, I used mplayer in the command line to play it.

```
mplayer dvd://2
```

It worked, so my thought was "If it plays libdvdcss must be installed", 
but then I heard of the command "ldconfig" and so I performed it, to search for libdvdcss

```
ldconfig -p | grep libdvdcss
```

but without any result, so I thought "If it is not listed by ldconfig, then libdvdcss does not exist"

My knowledge is too limited to understand, why it is so, could you share your ideas why it is so?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Comment: In `terminal`, type `dpkg -l *libdvdcss* | grep ii` and that will tell you if it's installed.